# Ассемблер,работа с файлами и папками

Tags: ассемблер

Как можно в ассемблере достать файлы из подкаталогов и вообще как зайти в подкаталоги??

Comment: Всё это полностью зависит от платформы, под которой вы работаете. Для DOS смотрите функции `4Eh` и `4Fh` прерывания `int 21h` в любом справочнике по окаменелостям.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если под DOS...

Зайти в подкаталог  -

> DOS 2+ - CHDIR - SET CURRENT DIRECTORY

AH = 3Bh
DS:DX -> ASCIZ pathname to become current directory (max 64 bytes)

Return:
CF clear if successful
AX destroyed
CF set on error
AX = error code (03h) (see #01680 at AH=59h/BX=0000h)

Notes: If new directory name includes a drive letter, the default drive is not changed, only the current directory on that drive. Changing the current directory also changes the directory in which FCB file calls operate. Under the FlashTek X-32 DOS extender, the pointer is in DS:EDX

А с файлом - что значит достать? Открыть? просто передавать полное имя с путем.

Список файлов? тогда, как справедливо заметил @PinkTux - 4Eh и 4Fh прерывания 21h.

Что до всяких функций - то в свое время [Ralf Brown's Interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm) был у любого программиста :)

Comment: Interrupt List - о, йес! Даже в виде всплывающей по хоткею резидентной таблицы :)